# wso2carbon development environment - mvn eclpse:eclipse or m2ecilpse?

Tags: wso2

I have checked out the carbon 4.1.0 source code, I now want to set up the source in eclipse.

How is this normally performed by wso2 developers?

- Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and import in to eclipse as standard eclipse projects
- Do not run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, just import into eclipse as maven projects

I presume the first option is performed as it is a more reliable approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `mvn eclipse:eclipse`  and import all files.

Comment: cool feature with eclipse 4.3 RC2 (kepler) - when importing, you can tell it to search for nested projects.